# EF Core 5.0.5 Add-Migration The string argument 'name' cannot be empty

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having an issue in regards with `Add-Migration` and gave me an error `The string argument 'name' cannot be empty.`. I tried executing this command like this: `Add-Migration Update_Add_User`.

Here is the error:

> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> System.ArgumentException: The string argument 'name' cannot be empty.
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper.Identifier(String name, ICollection`1 scope) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation operation, IndentedStringBuilder builder) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.Generate(String builderName, IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IndentedStringBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.CSharpMigrationsGenerator.GenerateMigration(String migrationNamespace, String migrationName, IReadOnlyList`1 upOperations, IReadOnlyList`1 downOperations)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> The string argument 'name' cannot be empty.

can anyone tell me how to fix this?

**Update: Nuget Packages**

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.5`
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 5.0.5`
`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.5`

Comment: can u try like ```Add-Migration  Update-Add-User``` that ?

Comment: There seems to be something in the definition/mapping of the table(s) being added which is confusing EF Core. Can you show the `User` class and related fluent configuration if any.

Comment: So the exception was thrown https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/v5.0.5/src/EFCore.Design/Migrations/Design/CSharpMigrationOperationGenerator.cs#L1113, because one of your column names is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the nuget package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` else you won't be able to run EF commands on the Package Manager Console.

`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 5.0.5`

Do you get the same error if you used
`dotnet ef add-migration nameOfMigration`?